# Changing UIWindow causes SVProgressHUD to not appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, svprogresshud

I have 2 UIWindows that I use in my app. In AppDelegate, in the method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: I simply have:

```
        self.windowStartup = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.windowSplit =  [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Then I set up self.windowSplit as a splitViewController and windowStartup with a xib as its rootViewController. **If I load windowSplit from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, then SVProgressHUD works great, however if I load windowStartup in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, then call:**

```
    [self.windowSplit makeKeyAndVisible];
```

**at a later time, SVProgressHUD won't work.** Everything else is working as expected. My desire is go get SVProgressHUD working for the 2nd scenario, but also to find out if there something I am doing wrong that could impact on anything else.

For a little more info, the reason why I am taking this approach is that I want to use the standard split view controller, however I want to load the startup view first, without it just appearing over the top of the splitView on the iPad. After the user has set things up they can decide if they want the startup view to show initially.

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

Edit:
Here is my code for startup:

```
   Startup *controller = [[Startup alloc] initWithNibName:@"Startup" bundle:nil];
    self.windowStartup.rootViewController = controller;
    [self.windowStartup makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: what will happen if you make windowSplit as the root Window of application & put the windowStartup on top of it.

Comment: Thanks @nsuinteger - I followed that path a little and have discovered that if windowStartup is ever displayed then SVProgressHUD won't work. So, I cannot run SVProgressHUD on windowStartup, whether I load it first or second. And SVProgressHUD will only work on splitView if I load that first. So I am clearly doing something wrong with startup. I'll edit the question with my code for startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple naming issue. I had issues with SVProgressHUD and ShareKit. Both were looking for the

```
    .window
```

property of my appDelegate. I went back to the standard

```
    UIWindow *window
```

and it works fine again.